# get regId phonegap pushplugin on android

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the regid of the device using a push plugin on phonegap:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

So I can have the regid onNotification, but I'l like to get the regId on an other way, when there is no notification.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear.